# how to add in rails 3 a form partial with ajax for fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, jquery, controller, nested-forms

i need really help

i have a multilevel form on one screen

product => productgroups => productmaterials

and i would like to add dynamically new fields_for productgroups and productmaterials in product edit and new.

productgroups belongs to materialgroups and
productmaterials belongs to materials (whereas material belongs to materialgroup)

i use simple_form gem for my forms so => in the product form i have inluded a fields_for partial for productgroups and inside productgroups i have another fields_for productmaterials.

now the user should select based on a select box a type of materialgroup, which he wants to add to the product as productgroup. inside the productgroup there should be a combobox of materials for adding productmaterials. each materialgroup and material have some specific settings of the field values. so i need to get the partial via ajax!

now the question: how to create a controller method for retrieving a fields_for partial of the product form?
Is that approach the correct direction or do i think somewhere wrong?

P.S.: edit form works

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). It use [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and allow you to add or remove your nested components.

Example of partial (`haml`):

```
.nested-fields
  .close.remove_photo
    = link_to_remove_association '', f
  = f.input :asset, :as => :image_preview
```

And here is a form_for (`haml`):

```
= place.simple_fields_for :photos do |photo|
  = render 'photo_fields', :f => photo
.links
  = link_to_add_association t('add_photo'), place, :photos
```

Comment: cocoon adds the "dummy"  rendered template in the data section of of the link (serverside) => but i need to specify which type of productgroup it should add. cocoon doesnt actually request via ajax. i could rewrite the JS to do so, but i dont know **how to create a seperate action in the controller render the partial with the fields_for form**. i get every time the error that the FormBuilder (f) variable is not instanciated